# "Subject election" at college/university

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering what is the name of process during which student chooses which subjects he/she going to attend to in next semester. After some thinking, "subject election" came to mind but somehow it doesn't feel right.

Is there any better alternative to this?

Comment: *Selection* instead of *election*.

Comment: Thanks, I've just read the difference between those two :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used "course selection."

Comment: Ah, that sounds better. Just a quick question: If my university has two groups of studies (say, hardware and software engineering) what would be a word for that? Thought about "department", but I'm not sure...

Comment: My university always called them departments, but I'm not sure about what you would call them if they're divisions within a department.

Comment: That's it! Division is the word I was looking for :) Thanks a lot :)